# Bash Command: What's the difference between a variable and an alias?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I'm new to linux and starting from the basics.

--
I thought alias is used to make a shortcut to a command.
But I tried the following using a variable (in Ubuntu) and still works!

```
$ foo="mkdir Directory"
$ $foo #this will create a directory named Directory
```

using alias:

```
$ alias bar="mkdir Directory"
$ bar #creates a Directory named directory
```

Is that how it is supposed to work?
Many thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Variables are much more versatile than aliases.  Variables can be used anywhere in a command line (e.g. as parts of program arguments), whereas aliases can *only* be used as the names of programs to run, i.e. as the first word in a command line.  For example:

```
foo="mkdir Directory"
echo $foo  # Prints "mkdir Directory"

alias bar="mkdir Directory"
echo bar  # Nothing gets expanded -- just "bar" is printed
```

Variables can also be exported into the environment of child processes.  If you use the [`export` builtin](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) to export variables, then programs can use [`getenv(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv) function to get the variables' values.

See the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) for a full description of all of the different types of expansions it can perform and how it performs them.  See also the section on [aliases](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases).

Comment: Cool!! I love all the answers but I have to choose this one.

Comment: Would you consider such solution (using variables) as good practise?

Answer (score 6):

"Variables are much more versatile than aliases" - not completely true!

For executing commands, variables have some limitations which are not shared by aliases.

Try using a variable to define a command that echoes a single asterisk to the command line:

```
$ myCommand="echo *"
$ $myCommand
file1.x file2.y file3.z
```

The * is expanded - which isn't what you wanted - so then try this:

```
$ myCommand="echo \"*\""
$ $myCommand
"*"
```

But now you have extra quotes appearing - you didn't want that either!

But this works OK:

```
$ echo "*"
*
```

And so does this:

```
$ alias myCommand="echo \"*\""
$ myCommand
*
```

This is because quotes inside a variable are treated as literal, rather than syntactical when a variable is expanded - so in this case they become part of the parameter that is passed to the echo command - whereas with an alias the command is executed "as is" and the quotes are treated as syntactical and are parsed out before echo is called, just as they are when you type the same command in directly from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that when you type the alias as if it were a command, you don't type the `$`; when you type a variable, you do have to include it. So aliases act more naturally as an alternate name for a command.

Answer (score 3):

In the variable form, it is expanded and evaluated.

Hence

```
$ $foo
```

is expanded to

```
$ mkdir Directory
```

which can be evaluated.  It's the same type of expansion as if foo were an argument:

```
$ echo $USER
```

For aliases, you reference them directly by using the name (no $) and it is only expanded if it is the first word.

Answer (score 0):

Variables replace their content wherever they are used.

```
$ foo="mkdir Directory"
$ $foo
$ echo "$foo"
```

Aliases act as actual commands, or rather the prefix of one.

```
$ alias bar="mkdir Directory"
$ bar directory2  #creates directories named "directory" and "directory2"
$ echo bar
```